# Boot2docker : image don't save

Tags: windows, docker, boot2docker

I'm starting to play with docker on my PC (windows 7) so I'm using Boot2Docker, but when I stop the VM all my work are remove. My questions are:

1. Why ?
2. How to solve this problems ?

Comment: What sort of work?  Boot2Docker is running a Linux VM with a regular filesystem inside, so anything you save to a file should still be there when you run it again.

Comment: boot2docker is a lightweight Linux distribution that runs from RAM.
If you want to persist data you need to use a persistence partition or a shared folder: https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#persist-data

Answer (score 0):

finally I resolve my problem:

2. Solution I've made a `boot2docker delete` and then a `boot2docker init`, when I `start`/`stop` the VM it works correctly (and it starts faster
3. Why : I don't know, the only possible reason is that I install boot2docker ant activate the VT-x in the BIOS after